# One - does common English usage equate that to "you" (2nd person) or "he/she" (3rd person)?

Tags: pronouns, gender-neutral

I am proof reading an academic paper on computer programming and am trying to ensure pronouns conform.  This is an example sentence:

> Accordingly, *one* considers some entry fees in *his* strategic bidding, even in a single-shot static auction...

Can one swap between "one" and "his"?

Comment: Certainly not within a single sentence, or any series of sentences where one is still referencing "the same" example person. If you've already used **one**, the possessive must be **one's**. Note that as in this comment, *one* can be juxtaposed/substituted for *you* or *me*, not *him*. But grammatically, **his** can never mean **one's**.

Comment: Thanks!  Instinct told me it was wrong, but I'm immensely reassured to have expert input.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, actually according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_%28pronoun%29#Possessive, **grammatically** you *can* do that. The problem is the semantic and gender neutrality. So, in case that 1) you have a male football team it is fine to say - "One should do his best not to provoke the official." 2) you are already using generic "he". Personally I don't like generic "he" and would not like to be perceived as if I was encouraging it, however the fact should be noted if we are looking strictly at grammar (and *if* wikipedia entry can be accepted; the article claims OED as reference).

Comment: In terms of style I think that in this case you can simply drop *his* without introducing ambiguity (which is not always the case): *Accordingly, one considers some entry fees in strategic bidding, even in a single-shot static auction...*

Comment: @Unreason: That Wikipedia page doesn't make any case for the (indefensible, IMHO) propostion that it's *grammatically* acceptable to conjoin *his* with *one*. It simply says people do this because they feel *one* is "stilted". They'll do anything to avoid repeating the awkward word too much.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the article states: "Either form is considered to be correct in formal English, but the form with "he" is sometimes viewed as sexist." and list OED (and another source as references). It might be, as you say, wrong - I am just bringing this to the attention.

Comment: @Unreason: Well, I don't want to get too bogged down in what "the authorities" say is "correct". But there's no doubt in my mind that use of *one takes his*, for example, [is declining](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+takes+one%27s%2Cone+takes+his&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I prefer to doubt myself, for example you are right over the range of 100 years yes, however in last 20, not so much http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+shows+his%2Cone+shows+one%27s&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 ; so this might be easily explained with the decline of use of the formal language. Also, this http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+can+take+one%27s%2Cone+can+take+his&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 shows *his* constantly used more often than the *one's* variant (according to you that's what matters).

Comment: We must be careful not to mix up the rights and wrongs of *our debate about shifting usage patterns* with OP's *question about 'correct' usage*. I guess mixing *one/his* doesn't bother you much anyway, so it suits you to see it as happening more often in recent years. With me it's the opposite, but I'd need to improve my skills at corpus searching before I could seriously put my case for saying that usage is declining. Maybe @Nohat will look into it - I think he's top gun round here when it comes to that kind of thing! :)

Comment: @Unreason: your ngrams searches are a little misleading.  Many hits for the *his* variants come from phrases of the form *No one can take his…*, which is a quite different situation.  So they don’t shows that the *his* variant is used “more often”; but I agree they do show that it’s used quite frequently.

Answer (score 8):

Traditionally, it should be **one's** here. If you introduce *one*, it should always be *one's*, *oneself*, etc. when referring to the same impersonal entity.

Burchfield tells us in *Fowler's Modern English Usage* that *his* was sometimes used in America, but he agrees that it is now conventionally *one's* everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much - I can now stop searching the web (which has been ultimately fruitless).

Comment: I knew I'd come across the (incorrect, to my ear) use of *his* as the possessive for *one*. You're right - it's an [Americanism](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/one.htm). They also sometimes use *your* instead of *one's* - presumably because *one* sounds dated and/or English and/or too starchily formal. They can bear to use **one** once in an utterance, but balk at using it again if they need the possessive form later in the sentence.

Comment: @Fumble: *Your*, really? As in, *one should deploy your troops on a near-by hill? One should brush your teeth*? I can't make it sound remotely natural. Neither formal nor informal context seems to work.

Comment: Check out my link, where it gives as an example of "incorrect" usage the statement *One must be conscientious about your dental hygiene.*

Comment: @Fumble: Ah. Funny. I must say that sounds very odd to me. Do you ever see it in serious writing?

Comment: That's a toughie. I think we're both *descriptivist* rather than *prescriptivist*, but personally I'm almost inclined to classify any example of this particular usage as *de facto* not "serious"! But I understand why people don't much like *one* to start with. There may well be subsets of speakers/writers who've actually gotten used to what sounds to me and you like a ridiculous way to avoid having to repeat *one* and *one's* in the same sentence. They should just avoid using *one* in the first place, but presumably they think *I/you/we* are too "informal".

Comment: It may be considered an Americanism by some, but the college entrance exam all students studying in the US have to take (the SAT) considers it grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I don’t have data to support this, but my own experience fits with what most people are saying: this use of *one* is more common in the UK (where for many people it’s not a marked usage at all) than the US (where for most people it’s at least a very formal usage); but when it is used in the US, then it’s more likely to be paired with *his*, which to a UK ear is simply wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you use *one* as your pronoun, **you should not substitute in either *you* or *s/he* to represent the same person.**

The prose should be consistent throughout:

*One must mind one's manners.*

*You must mind your manners.*

*He must mind his manners.*

etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's grammatical, but could be objected to on grounds of gender inequality. If the writer must use *one*, then it has to be *Accordingly, one considers some entry fees in one's strategic bidding . . .*  But there must be some other way of putting it.

Comment: Thank you - for responding so quickly and for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: I've just followed a link to this thread, Barrie. You say it's grammatical; others say it's not 'acceptable'. Have you a counter-reference for Fowler?

Comment: ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ finds a problem with both ‘one’s’ (‘the repetition . . . draws attention to its awkwardness’) and with either ‘his’ or ‘her’ (‘because of their perceived sexism’). That leaves a third option, ‘their’. That may be criticised , ‘because it follows the singular “one” with the plural “their”’. The Guide continues, however, with ‘That kind of agreement is however increasingly common after other indefinite pronouns . . . and avoids gender complications.’

Answer (score 0):

Substituting *his* for *one*:

> Accordingly, his considers some entry fees in his strategic bidding...

wouldn't be appropriate since the sentence is neither consistent, as [onomatomaniak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46468/one-does-common-english-usage-equate-that-to-you-2nd-person-or-he-she-3/46469#46469) suggests, nor is it gender neutral.

Keeping them consistent by substituting *one's* for *his*:

> Accordingly, one considers some entry fees in one's strategic bidding...

or *he* for *one*:

> Accordingly, he considers some entry fees in his strategic bidding...

work well though.

Unfortunately, in the latter case, the example has lost its gender neutrality.