# What's the error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What's the error in the following sentence?

"One must not boast of his own talents."

Kindly provide me some answers, Thank you.

Comment: **One must not boast of his or her own talents.** One can also mean a female.

Comment: @JayHook that is not an error, though. That's a purely political argument, not a linguistic one.

Comment: I don't see an error in this sentence.

Comment: related: [One - does common English usage equate that to “you” (2nd person) or “he/she” (3rd person)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46468/one-does-common-english-usage-equate-that-to-you-2nd-person-or-he-she-3)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> One must not boast of one's own talents.

Or if you wanted to keep the "his" because you are referring to a specific (male) person:

> He must not boast of his own talents.

Comment: According to which authority? [An article at grammar.ccc.com](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/one.htm) contains: In the United States, the possessive and reflexive forms of one — one's and oneself — are often replaced by other pronoun forms. In British English, they are commonplace:

_One must be conscientious about one's dental hygiene._ In the U.S. that one's is apt to be replaced by a third-person "his" or (more informally) a second-person "your":


_One must be conscientious about one's [or his] dental hygiene.
One must be conscientious about your dental hygiene._